# How To Create A Dataframe Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dictionary of Pandas Series objects that I want to turn into a Dataframe. The key for each series should be the column heading. The individual series overlap but, each label is unique.

I thought I should be able to just do

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

But I keep getting the error `InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`.

I get the same error if I try to turn each series into a frame, and use `pd.concat(data, axis=1)`.

Which doesn't make sense if you take the column label into account. What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: could you provide an example of the `data` dictionary?

Comment: Yeah, working on it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) with parameter `drop=True` of each `Series` in `dict` comprehension, because duplicates in index:

```
s = pd.Series([1,4,5,2,0], index=[1,2,2,3,5])
s1 = pd.Series([5,7,8,1],index=[1,2,3,4])

data = {'a':s, 'b': s1}

print (s.reset_index(drop=True))
0    1
1    4
2    5
3    2
4    0
dtype: int64

df = pd.concat({k:v.reset_index(drop=True) for k,v in data.items()}, axis=1)
print (df)
   a    b
0  1  5.0
1  4  7.0
2  5  8.0
3  2  1.0
4  0  NaN
```

If you need drop rows where duplicated index use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.duplicated.html):

```
print (s[~s.index.duplicated()])
1    1
2    4
3    2
5    0
dtype: int64
df = pd.concat({k:v[~v.index.duplicated()] for k,v in data.items()}, axis=1)
print (df)
     a    b
1  1.0  5.0
2  4.0  7.0
3  2.0  8.0
4  NaN  1.0
5  0.0  NaN
```

Another solution:

```
print (s.groupby(level=0).mean())
1    1.0
2    4.5
3    2.0
5    0.0
dtype: float64

df = pd.concat({k:v.groupby(level=0).mean() for k,v in data.items()}, axis=1)
print (df)
     a    b
1  1.0  5.0
2  4.5  7.0
3  2.0  8.0
4  NaN  1.0
5  0.0  NaN
```

Comment: That makes sense, given the error message. But what if I want to the same timestamps in the different series to line up? Won't this cause all the indices to just become integers?

Comment: I'm an idiot. I understand your answer. There's a bug in my code creating duplicate timestamps I wasn't expecting.